# How to pass changing int value from one class to another libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I need to pass in my score int value to another screen. I tried using:

```
public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
} 
public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    setScore(score);
```

}

and in the other class

```
int score = 0;
public end(Gamechanger gam){  
MyGdxGame mygame = new MyGdxGame(game);    
score = mygame.getscore();
```

}

but when i play it, the score says 0.

also tried

```
public void render(float delta){
score = mygame.score;
```

}

but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preferences for that:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences